# Saving bytes instead of objects to write smaller files

Tags: game, objective-c, bitwise, serialization, compression

This question is about reducing the size of files saved to disk in an infinite world 2D mining game.

I finally added code to my game to save and load distant chunks instead of keeping all of them in memory.  Up to this point, I had only used the default NSCoding Apple library to save and load files from disk.  In my initial testing, each `Chunk` consisted of 900 Blocks, and when saved to disk the file was `160kb`.  This would mean that worlds with just a few million blocks could be bigger than a gigabyte.

I tried a number of different methods to decrease the size of the files.  I found some code on Stack Overflow to implement some gzip compression, and that reduced the size down to about `74kb`.  This was good, but not nearly good enough.  The next thing I tried was to reduce the amount of information stored in each block. I removed all the `NSStrings`, and derived those from other values instead of saving them. I converted all the `CGPoints` to `ints`, and saved those instead.  This got the file size down to about `52kb`.  This was almost small enough to work, but I knew I could do better.

The `Blocks` themselves only had a very small amount of information stored in them.  I decided to manually compose the bytes needed to initialize a block, and then manually parse those bytes when the file was loaded.

I succeeded in writing some code to do this, and it got the file size down to `4kb`. Each `Block` is `28 bytes`, so this is much closer to a reasonable number. I should note that when I tried without the gzip compression, the file size rose to `25kb`.  I decided to use the Apple libraries to do this, so I am reading and writing to `NSData`.  I believe there are better ways to achieve this, and I would love to hear about them.

**DWBlock.m**

```
#pragma mark - Custom encode and decode
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        int theBytesRecovered[7];
        [data getBytes:theBytesRecovered];

        _type = (int)theBytesRecovered[0];
        _damageLevel = (int)theBytesRecovered[1];
        _chunkSize = (int)theBytesRecovered[2];

        int posX = (int)theBytesRecovered[3];
        int posY = (int)theBytesRecovered[4];
        int chunkPosX = (int)theBytesRecovered[5];
        int chunkPosY = (int)theBytesRecovered[6];
        _position = CGPointMake(posX, posY);
        _chunkPosition = CGPointMake(chunkPosX, chunkPosY);

        _blockName = NSStringFromCGPoint(_position);
        _chunkName = NSStringFromCGPoint(_chunkPosition);
        _calculatedPosition = CGPointMake((_chunkPosition.x * _chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth) + (_position.x * kBlockSpriteWidth), (_chunkPosition.y * _chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth) + (_position.y * kBlockSpriteWidth));
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSData *) customEncode {
    int type = _type;
    int damageLevel = _damageLevel;
    int chunkSize = _chunkSize;
    int posX = _position.x;
    int posY = _position.y;
    int chunkPosX = _chunkPosition.x;
    int chunkPosY = _chunkPosition.y;

    int theBytes[] = {type, damageLevel, chunkSize, posX, posY, chunkPosX, chunkPosY};

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:&theBytes length:sizeof(theBytes)];
}
```

**DWChunk.m**

```
#pragma mark - Custom encode and decode
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _memConstants = [[DWMemoryConstants alloc]init];

        //Iterate through the chunk data
        //Grab the correct number of bytes for each block
        //Compose a new NSData out of those bytes, and add them to an array
        NSMutableArray *blockDatas = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        uint8_t *bytePtr = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];
        NSInteger totalData = [data length] / sizeof(uint8_t);
        for (int i = 0; i < totalData; i+=kChunkSizeInBytes) {
            NSMutableData *blockData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
            for (int j = 0; j < kChunkSizeInBytes; j++) {
                [blockData appendBytes:&bytePtr[i + j] length:1];
            }
            [blockDatas addObject:blockData];
        }

        //Create the Block objects
        _blocks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        BOOL firstRun = YES;
        for (NSData *data in blockDatas) {
            DWBlock *block = [[DWBlock alloc]initWithData:data];
            //Get some data about this Chunk from the first block
            if (firstRun) {
                _position = CGPointFromString(block.chunkName);
                firstRun = NO;
            }
            [_blocks setObject:block forKey:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(block.blockName)]];
        }

        _chunkName = NSStringFromCGPoint(_position);
        _bounds = CGRectMake(_position.x * _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _position.y * _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth);
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSData *) customEncode {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    for (DWBlock *block in _blocks.allValues) {
        //It is very important to get the bytes of the NSData and not just the pointer
        [data appendBytes:[[block customEncode]bytes] length:[[block customEncode]length]];
    }

    return data;
}
```

Chunks are saved like this:

```
for (DWChunk *chunk in chunks) {
    NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"worldtest%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(chunk.position)]];
    NSData *data = [chunk customEncode];
    data = [DWDataZipper gzipDeflate:data];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

And loaded like this:

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"worldtest%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(position.CGPointValue)]];
NSData *chunkData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (chunkData) {
    chunkData = [DWDataZipper gzipInflate:chunkData];
    DWChunk *chunk = [[DWChunk alloc]initWithData:chunkData];
}
```

Comment: I can't make any suggestions in terms of tuning strategy, however maybe some alternative approaches. Can you apply archiving to the disk or a different storage strategy besides just disk?

Archive older disk files that might not be used or using a different storage mechanism such that you could use both disk and alternative saving location for certain check points. Then re-access that data later. Obviously wouldn't be as fast as having it on disk but might free up some space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do chunkLength = chunkPosY-chunkPosX or length = posY-posX have a max limit?
Does damageLevel, type have a max value say 10.
Did you try using a structure and writing that to the file (as in C). A few benefits include:

- Bit field usage.
- Easy retrieval and storing instead of storing block metadata.

  ```
  struct NSData { 
      int type :4; // bitfield usage since the max type is 10(1010)
      int damageLevel:4; // bitfield usage since max damageLevel is 8(1000)
      int posX;
      int posY; // If length = posY-posX has a max level with limited bitfield usage; Use it.
      int chunkSize; //Is this a part of the actual data to be stored.
      int chunkPosX;
      int chunkPosY; // Same as above.
  }
  ```

I have used structs in C and the size is almost equal to the calculated size, i.e.

```
sizeof(NSData) * number of NSData
```

One observation: 
Since all your data are numbers, if each item's value does not exceed '999'(3 characters), you can serialize it to a string delimited with any character and save it.

```
    2|5|22|35|123|24|98; // This will occupy less bytes instead of 28 bytes.
    decimal-value delimiter string-end-delimiter. // uses 19 bytes
    2|5|F6|23|7B|F8|62;
    hex-value  delimiter string-end-delimiter. //20Bytes
```

**Note**: `kb = KiloBits; kB = KiloBytes.` 
(Unsure how 900Blocks * 28Bytes < 24KB)